# Retrive host name from environment variable DISPLAY in Makefile

Tags: makefile, environment-variables, substring

Suppose my environment variable DISPLAY is "mypc:0.0", how could I retrieve the hostname part "mypc" in a Makefile?

I have tried something like 
`@echo $(patsubst :0.0,,$(DISPLAY))`
without any luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `$(patsubst %:0.0,%,$(DISPLAY))`.

Comment: @Renaud Pacalet It works. Could you please give it as an answer, so that I could flag it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct use of `patsubst` in this case is:

```
$(patsubst %:0.0,%,$(DISPLAY))
```

(the `:0/0` pattern does not match `mypc:0.0` while `%:0.0` does).